Tiempo de ejecución demorado en SQL Server Management Studio 19
Tengo la siguiente query:
USE Parcial_script; 
GO

SELECT 
    (SELECT Expediente FROM TExpediente WHERE idExpediente = T.idExpediente) AS Expediente, 
    (SELECT Producto FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto) AS Producto, 
    (SELECT CompaniaTitular FROM TExpediente WHERE idExpediente = T.idExpediente) AS CompaniaTitular, 
    (SELECT RegistroSanitario FROM TExpediente WHERE idExpediente = T.idExpediente) AS RegistroSanitario, 
    (SELECT FechaExpedicion FROM TExpediente WHERE idExpediente = T.idExpediente) AS FechaExpedicion, 
    (SELECT FechaVencimiento FROM TExpediente WHERE idExpediente = T.idExpediente) AS FechaVencimiento, 
    (SELECT EstadoRegistro FROM TExpediente WHERE idExpediente = T.idExpediente) AS EstadoRegistro, 
    (SELECT ExpedienteCum FROM TExpedienteCum WHERE idExpedienteCum = T.idExpedienteCum) AS ExpedienteCum, 
    (SELECT ConsecutivoCum FROM TExpedienteCum WHERE idExpedienteCum = T.idExpedienteCum) AS ConsecutivoCum, 
    (SELECT CantidadPorEnvase FROM TEnvase WHERE idEnvase = T.idEnvase) AS CantidadPorEnvase, 
    (SELECT DescripcionComercial FROM TEnvase WHERE idEnvase = T.idEnvase) AS DescripcionComercial, 
    (SELECT EstadoCum FROM TExpedienteCum WHERE idExpedienteCum = T.idExpedienteCum) AS EstadoCum, 
    (SELECT FechaActivo FROM TExpedienteCum WHERE idExpedienteCum = T.idExpedienteCum) AS FechaActivo, 
    (SELECT FechaInactivo FROM TExpedienteCum WHERE idExpedienteCum = T.idExpedienteCum) AS FechaInactivo, 
    (SELECT MuestraMedica FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto) AS MuestraMedica, 
    (SELECT UnidadDeMedida FROM TUnidadDeMedida WHERE idUnidadMedida = (SELECT idUnidadMedida FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS UnidadDeMedida, 
    (SELECT ATC FROM TATC WHERE idATC = (SELECT idATC FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS ATC, 
    (SELECT DescripcionATC FROM TATC WHERE idATC = (SELECT idATC FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS DescripcionATC, 
    (SELECT ViaAdministracion FROM TViaAdministracion WHERE idViaAdministracion = (SELECT idViaAdministracion FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS ViaAdministracion, 
    (SELECT ConcentracionMedicamento FROM TConcentracion WHERE idConcentracion = (SELECT idConcentracion FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS ConcentracionMedicamento, 
    (SELECT PrincipioActivo FROM TPrincipioActivo WHERE idPrincipioActivo = T.idPrincipioActivo) AS PrincipioActivo, 
    (SELECT UnidadPrincipioActivo FROM TUnidadPrincipioActivo WHERE idUPrincipioActivo = (SELECT idUPrincipioActivo FROM TPrincipioActivo WHERE idPrincipioActivo = T.idPrincipioActivo)) AS UnidadPrincipioActivo, 
    (SELECT CantidadPrincipioActivo FROM TPrincipioActivo WHERE idPrincipioActivo = T.idPrincipioActivo) AS CantidadPrincipioActivo, 
    (SELECT UnidadReferencia FROM TUnidadReferencia WHERE idUnidadReferencia = (SELECT idUnidadReferencia FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS UnidadReferencia, 
    (SELECT FormaFarmaceutica FROM TFormaFarmaceutica WHERE idFormaFarmaceutica = (SELECT idFormaFarmaceutica FROM TMedicamento WHERE idProducto = T.idProducto)) AS FormaFarmaceutica, 
    (SELECT NombreRol FROM TEmpresa WHERE idEmpresa = T.idEmpresa) AS NombreRol, 
    (SELECT Rol FROM TRol WHERE idRol = (SELECT idRol FROM TEmpresa WHERE idEmpresa = T.idEmpresa)) AS Rol, 
    (SELECT Modalidad FROM TModalidad WHERE idModalidad = (SELECT idModalidad FROM TEmpresa WHERE idEmpresa = T.idEmpresa)) AS Modalidad, 
    (SELECT IUM FROM TMedicamento WHERE IUM = (SELECT IUM FROM Base_Datos WHERE IUM = TMedicamento.IUM)) AS IUM, 
    (SELECT Orden FROM Base_Datos WHERE Orden = (SELECT Orden FROM Base_Datos WHERE Orden = T.Orden)) AS Orden 
FROM TVigencia T 
ORDER BY Orden;

El problema es que lo ejecuto y nunca termina, ha durado 2 horas y nada, siempre toca cancelarlo, lo curioso es que tengo otro query donde hay mucho más código, con éste incluido pero se demora 15 segundos en terminar de ejecutar, no entiendo el porqué, alguien me puede explicar?

Puedes intentar haciendo subconsultas una a una para ver cuál es el problema, tal vez sea una de ellas la que no permita terminar

Me di cuenta de lo siguiente, el problema no es la creación de la vista, sino al momento de usar select * from VSentencia2;
Al ejecutar este select, no termina nunca, sabes a que se debe?

No habrá algo / alguien que este accediendo a dicha tabla? Puedes intentar algunas de las soluciones de acá Solución de problemas de consultas que parecen nunca completarse en SQL Server - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn

Tu pregunta no puede responderse solo viendo la sentencia sin el plan de ejecución,. De entrada, me parece curioso que hagas tantas sub-consultas, cuando lo natural sería hacer joins, pero pienso que el motor debiera ser capaz de traducir tu estilo en una serie de joins. Si realmente buscas una respuesta, incluye el plan de ejecución en la pregunta.

Empecemos por aclarar que esta consulta nunca será eficiente. Necesita condiciones en el WHERE para poder limitar el número de filas devueltas y poder utilizar correctamente los índices.
Sin embargo, la estructura de la consulta es desastroza porque está haciendo lecturas independientes a las tablas por cada columna y cada fila. Eso hace que el tiempo de ejecución se eleve muchísimo y no habrá recursos suficientes para que esto funcione a gran escala. En su lugar, es importante utilizar JOINs para poder unir tablas de forma eficiente. Dejo un ejemplo de como podría ser, aunque es posible que necesite ajustes con las clausulas y cambiar INNER JOIN por LEFT JOIN en algunos casos.
SELECT 
     EX.Expediente                 AS Expediente, 
     M.Producto                    AS Producto, 
     EX.CompaniaTitular            AS CompaniaTitular, 
     EX.RegistroSanitario          AS RegistroSanitario, 
     EX.FechaExpedicion            AS FechaExpedicion, 
     EX.FechaVencimiento           AS FechaVencimiento, 
     EX.EstadoRegistro             AS EstadoRegistro, 
     EC.ExpedienteCum              AS ExpedienteCum, 
     EC.ConsecutivoCum             AS ConsecutivoCum, 
     EN.CantidadPorEnvase          AS CantidadPorEnvase, 
     EN.DescripcionComercial       AS DescripcionComercial,
     EC.EstadoCum                  AS EstadoCum, 
     EC.FechaActivo                AS FechaActivo, 
     EC.FechaInactivo              AS FechaInactivo, 
     M.MuestraMedica               AS MuestraMedica, 
     UM.UnidadDeMedida             AS UnidadDeMedida, 
     ATC.ATC                       AS ATC, 
     ATC.DescripcionATC            AS DescripcionATC, 
     VA.ViaAdministracion          AS ViaAdministracion, 
     C.ConcentracionMedicamento    AS ConcentracionMedicamento, 
     PA.PrincipioActivo            AS PrincipioActivo, 
     UPA.UnidadPrincipioActivo     AS UnidadPrincipioActivo,
     PA.CantidadPrincipioActivo    AS CantidadPrincipioActivo, 
     UR.UnidadReferencia           AS UnidadReferencia, 
     FF.FormaFarmaceutica          AS FormaFarmaceutica, 
     EM.NombreRol                  AS NombreRol, 
     R.Rol                         AS Rol, 
     MO.Modalidad                  AS Modalidad, 
     I.IUM                         AS IUM, 
     BD.Orden                      AS Orden 
FROM TVigencia                    AS V
INNER JOIN TExpediente            AS EX  ON V.idExpediente        = EX.idExpediente
INNER JOIN TMedicamento           AS M   ON V.idProducto          = M.idProducto
INNER JOIN TExpedienteCum         AS EC  ON V.idExpedienteCum     = EC.idExpedienteCum
INNER JOIN TEnvase                AS EN  ON V.idEnvase            = EN.idEnvase
INNER JOIN TUnidadDeMedida        AS UM  ON M.idUnidadMedida      = UM.idUnidadMedida
INNER JOIN TATC                   AS ATC ON M.idATC               = ATC.idATC
INNER JOIN TViaAdministracion     AS VA  ON M.idViaAdministracion = VA.idViaAdministracion
INNER JOIN TConcentracion         AS C   ON M.idConcentracion     = C.idConcentracion 
INNER JOIN TPrincipioActivo       AS PA  ON V.idPrincipioActivo   = PA.idPrincipioActivo      
INNER JOIN TUnidadPrincipioActivo AS UPA ON PA.idUPrincipioActivo = UPA.idUPrincipioActivo
INNER JOIN TUnidadReferencia      AS UR  ON M.idUnidadReferencia  = UR.idUnidadReferencia
INNER JOIN TFormaFarmaceutica     AS FF  ON M.idUnidadReferencia  = FF.idUnidadReferencia
INNER JOIN TEmpresa               AS EM  ON V.idEmpresa           = EM.idEmpresa
INNER JOIN TRol                   AS R   ON EM.idRol              = T.idRol
INNER JOIN TModalidad             AS MO  ON EM.idModalidad        = MO.idModalidad
INNER JOIN Base_Datos             AS BD  ON V.Orden               = BD.Orden
INNER JOIN TMedicamento           AS I   ON BD.IUM                = I.IUM
ORDER BY Orden;

